# Getting error in catalog product price indexing

Tags: reindex, magento-2.1.8, magento-ee

I am facing below error while running indexing for catalog product price.

**Command:**

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_price

**Error:**

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`m2ec_oct`.`catalog_product_index_price`, CONSTRAINT
>   `CAT_PRD_IDX_PRICE_ENTT_ID_SEQUENCE_PRD_SEQUENCE_VAL` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `sequence_product` (`sequence_value`) ON
>   DELETE ), query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price`
>   (`entity_id`, `customer_group_id`, `website_id`, `tax_class_id`,
>   `price`, `final_price`, `min_price`, `max_price`, `tier_price`) SELECT
>   `catalog_product_index_price_idx`.`entity_id`,
>   `catalog_product_index_price_idx`.`customer_group_id`,
>   `catalog_product_index_price_idx`.`website_id`,
>   `catalog_product_index_price_idx`.`tax_class_id`,
>   `catalog_product_index_price_idx`.`price`,
>   `catalog_product_index_price_idx`.`final_price`,
>   `catalog_product_index_price_idx`.`min_price`,
>   `catalog_product_index_price_idx`.`max_price`,
>   `catalog_product_index_price_idx`.`tier_price` FROM
>   `catalog_product_index_price_idx` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `entity_id`
>   = VALUES(`entity_id`), `customer_group_id` = VALUES(`customer_group_id`), `website_id` = VALUES(`website_id`),
>   `tax_class_id` = VALUES(`tax_class_id`), `price` = VALUES(`price`),
>   `final_price` = VALUES(`final_price`), `min_price` =
>   VALUES(`min_price`), `max_price` = VALUES(`max_price`), `tier_price` =
>   VALUES(`tier_price`)

Please let me know if anyone has faced this issue before.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting index using below command

> php bin/magento indexer:reset catalog_product_price

Then try

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_price

Comment: Tried but No working, getting the same error :(

Comment: Ok please check SKU of all products. If their length exceed limit then also this error occurs. Check this link. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/247781/75828

Comment: If still not solved then run php bin/magento indexer:reindex without any additional option. So it will reindex all data and any inconsistency will be removed.

Comment: Thank Khushbu But still it is not working, getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

For me the `sequence_product` table had some missing values for some reason

```
mysql> insert into sequence_product (sequence_value) select entity_id from catalog_product_entity where entity_id not in(select sequence_value from sequence_product);
Query OK, 29 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 29  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Running the above query added in missing entity IDs and the reindex completed successfully.